# Android locationManager works with 5.02 but in 4.4.2 only with network provider

Tags: android, service, gps, geolocation

I'm trying to get user coordenates in my app, it's a worker tracking app. My locationManager is started as a service to keep tracking when the activity is closed.

Service:

```
public class ServiceGPS extends Service implements LocationListener {

private Context mContext;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

private int MIN_DISTANCIA_MOVIDA = 5;
private int MIN_TEMPO = 20;
private int QUALIDADE_HORIZONTAL = 2;
private int QUALIDADE_VERTICAL = 2;
private String provider;

public ServiceGPS() {}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (verificaGpsNetwork(locationManager)) {
            iniciaGPS();
        }
        else {
            showSettingsAlert();
        }

}// onStart

public void iniciaGPS() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(QUALIDADE_HORIZONTAL);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(QUALIDADE_VERTICAL);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TEMPO, MIN_DISTANCIA_MOVIDA, this);
    }
    else
        showSettingsAlert();
}// iniciaGPS

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        registraLocalizacao(location);

}// onLocationChanged

}
```

It works fine in 5.0.2, but location always comes NULL in 4.4.2.

Is there a problem using GPS provider as a service? With

```
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

provider returns GPS, and the GPS icon does keep showing (even with the aplication closed, so the service seems to be OK), but never returns any location, and if I try to use

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
```

always comes back NULL. In the other hand if I just set my provider as 'network' the onLocationChanged is called with the coordenates.

So, whats up with that? Any work around on that?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry but no. Sadly the only 'work around' that I found was use Google Location Services API, hole other aproach. Example: http://www.toptal.com/android/android-developers-guide-to-google-location-services-api